Usage of transitivity theorem
Here is the formalization I am using:
(* Atomic proposition. *)
Parameter atom : Set.

(* We assume atomic propositions form a set with decidable equality. *)
Parameter atom_eq : forall (a b : atom), {a = b} + {a <> b}.

(* Propositional formulas *)
Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Declare Scope formula_scope.
Open Scope formula_scope.
Declare Custom Entry formula_view.

(* Filling the notaions according to priority *)
Notation "x" := x (x ident, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "( p )" := p (p custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "~ p" := (f_not p) (p custom formula_view at level 1, in custom formula_view at level 1).

(*
Implication is weaker then conjuncion and disjunction, but it is required for their
definitions, that's why we introduce it's notation beforehand
*)
Notation "p -> q" := (f_imp p q) (q custom formula_view at level 4, in custom formula_view at level 4).

Notation "'$' p '$'" := p (format "'$' p '$'", p custom formula_view at level 5, at level 0).

Check fun p q => f_imp (f_imp (f_not (f_atom q)) (f_not (f_atom p))) (f_imp (f_atom p) (f_atom q)).
Definition conjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~ (A -> ~ B)$.
Notation "A /\ B" := (conjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 2, in custom formula_view at level 2, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition disjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~A -> B$.
Notation "A \/ B" := (disjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 3, in custom formula_view at level 3, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition equivalence (A B: formula) : formula := $(A -> B) /\ (B -> A)$.
Notation "A <-> B" := (equivalence A B) (B custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 5, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* Equality of formulas is decidable. *)
Lemma formula_eq (A B : formula) : {A = B} + {A <> B}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  now apply atom_eq.
Qed.

(* Instead of working with lists of assumptions we shall work with
   sets of assumptions. A set of formulas can be represented by its
   characteristic map formula -> Prop. *)

(* Element-hood relation between a formula and a set of formulas. *)
Definition elem (A : formula) (Γ : formula -> Prop) := Γ A.
Infix "∈" := elem (at level 77) : formula_scope.

(* The empty context. *)
Definition empty : formula -> Prop := fun _ => False.

(* The union of two sets of formulas. *)
Definition union (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) A := A ∈ Γ \/ A ∈ Δ.
Infix "∪" := union (at level 78, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* The subset relation between sets of formulas. *)
Definition subset (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) :=
  forall A, A ∈ Γ -> A ∈ Δ.
Infix "⊆" := subset (at level 79) : formula_scope.

(* We now come to main definitions. We first define a type
   Γ |- A whose elements are derivations of formula A
   from assumptions Γ. These are presented as derivation trees,
   rather than more traditional lists.

   Note the difference between declaring that Γ |- A
   is a Prop vs. a Type:

   - if Γ |- A is a Prop, then it is expresses *provability*
   - if Γ |- A is a Type, then it expresses *proof derivations*

   The practical difference is this: if Γ |- A is a Type, then
   its element is a derivation tree which can be freely inspected
   and used; but if Γ |- A is a Prop, then its elements are
   (abstract) witnesses of provability that can only be expected
   for the purpose of constructing an element of Prop.
 *)
Reserved Notation "Γ |- A" (at level 98).
Inductive entails (Γ : formula -> Prop) : formula -> Type :=
  | hypo : forall A, A ∈ Γ -> Γ |- A (* every hypothesis is provable *)
  | axiom1 : forall A B , Γ |- $A -> B -> A$
  | axiom2 : forall A B C, Γ |- $(A -> B -> C) -> (A -> B) -> (A -> C)$
  | axiom3 : forall A B, Γ |- $(~ B -> ~ A) -> (~ B -> A) -> B$
  | mp : forall A B, Γ |- B -> Γ |- $B -> A$ -> Γ |- A (* modus ponens *)
where "Γ |- A" := (entails Γ A).

(* It is convenient to make some parameters implicit. *)
Arguments hypo {_} {_} _.
Arguments axiom1 {_} _ _.
Arguments axiom2 {_} _ _ _.
Arguments axiom3 {_} _ _.
Arguments mp {_} {_} (_).

(* Here are some basic observation about |-. *)

Lemma imply_self Γ A : Γ |- $A -> A$.
Proof.
  apply mp with (B := $A -> A -> A$).
  - exact (axiom1 A A).
  - apply mp with (B := $A -> (A -> A) -> A$).
    + exact (axiom1 A $A -> A$).
    + exact (axiom2 A $A -> A$ A).
Qed.

(* Weakening: having more hypotheses does not hurt. *)
Theorem weaken Γ Δ A : Γ ⊆ Δ -> Γ |- A -> Δ |- A.
Proof.
  intros S H.
  induction H as [B H|?|?|?|C D K L IH1 IH2].
  - unfold subset in S.
    specialize (S B H).
    exact (@hypo Δ B S).
  - apply (axiom1 A B).
  - apply (axiom2 A B C).
  - apply (axiom3 A B).
  - apply mp with (B := D).
    + exact L.
    + exact IH2.
Qed.

(* "extend Γ A" is the set Γ ∪ {A}. *)
Definition extend Γ A := fun B => or (B ∈ Γ) (A = B).

(* The cut rule is admissible. *)
Theorem CutRule A {Γ B} : Γ |- A -> extend Γ A  |- B -> Γ |- B.
Proof.
  intros H G.
  induction G as [B L|?|?|?|?].
  - destruct (formula_eq A B) as [Heq|Hneq].
    + rewrite <- Heq. exact H.
    + apply hypo.
      destruct L as [Hin|Heq].
      * exact Hin.
      * specialize (Hneq Heq). destruct Hneq.
  - apply axiom1.
  - apply axiom2.
  - apply axiom3.
  - apply (mp B).
    + apply IHG1.
    + apply IHG2.
Qed.

(* We need this lemma in the deduction theorem. *)
Lemma drop_antecedent Γ A B : Γ |- B -> Γ |- $A -> B$.
Proof.
  intro H.
  apply (mp B).
  - exact H.
  - apply axiom1.
Qed.

(* We conclude with the proof of the deduction theorem, just to show
   that it is quite painless to formalize. *)
Theorem deduction {Γ A B} : extend Γ A |- B -> Γ |- $A -> B$.
Proof.
  intro H.
  induction H as [B G|?|?|?|C].
  - destruct (formula_eq A B) as [Heq|Hneq].
    + rewrite Heq.
      apply imply_self.
    + apply mp with (B := B).
      * apply hypo.
        destruct G as [Hin|Heq].
        ++ exact Hin.
        ++ contradiction.
      * apply axiom1.
  - apply drop_antecedent.
    apply axiom1.
  - apply drop_antecedent.
    apply axiom2.
  - apply drop_antecedent.
    apply axiom3.
  - apply (mp ($A -> B$)).
    + assumption.
    + apply (mp ($A -> B -> C$)).
      * assumption.
      * apply axiom2.
Qed.

We proved 2 theorems of transitivity that will be used in the future:
Ltac hypo := (apply hypo ; unfold extend, elem ; auto 6).

Theorem transitivity1 Γ A B C (H1 : $A -> B$ ∈ Γ) (H2 : $B -> C$ ∈ Γ) :
  Γ |- $A -> C$.
Proof.
  apply deduction.
  (* extend Γ A |- C*)
  apply (mp B).
  (* extend Γ A |- B -> extend Γ A |- B ~> C -> extend Γ A |- C *)
  - apply (mp A).
    (* extend Γ A |- A -> extend Γ A |- A ~> B -> extend Γ A |- B *)
    * hypo. (* extend Γ A |- A *)
    * hypo. (* extend Γ A |- A ~> B *)
  - hypo.   (* extend Γ A |- B ~> C *)
Qed.

Theorem transitivity2 Γ A B C (H1 : ($A -> B -> C$) ∈ Γ) (H2 : B ∈ Γ) :
  Γ |- $A -> C$.
Proof.
  apply deduction.
  apply mp with (B := B).
  (* extend Γ A |- B -> extend Γ A |- B ~> C -> extend Γ A |- C *)
  - hypo.
  - apply mp with (B := A).
    * hypo.
    * hypo.
Qed.

Now I tried to formalize the examples from the book.
Here is the first one:
a. ⊢ ¬¬B -> B

Proof
1. (¬B -> ¬¬B) -> ((¬B -> ¬B) -> B)   Axiom (A3)
2. ¬B -> ¬B                           Lemma 1.8 : ⊢ A -> A
3. (¬B -> ¬¬B) -> B                   1, 2, Corollary 1.10(b): B -> (C -> D), C ⊢ B -> D
4. ¬¬B -> (¬B -> ¬¬B)                 Axiom (A1)
5. ¬¬B -> B                           3, 4, Corollary 1.10(a): B -> C, C -> D ⊢ B -> D

Here is the formal proof corresponding to the informal:
Ltac is_hypo := (repeat (unfold extend, elem) ; auto 6).
Theorem neg_neg_pos Γ B : Γ |- $~~ B -> B$.
Proof.
  (* 1 *)
  set (Fax3 := $(~B -> ~~B) -> (~B -> ~B) -> B$).
  apply CutRule with (A := Fax3).
  apply axiom3.
  (* 2 *)
  set (FnB_nB := $~B -> ~B$).
  apply CutRule with (A := FnB_nB).
  apply imply_self.
  (* 3 *)
  set (F3 := $(~B -> ~~B) -> B$).
  apply CutRule with (A := F3).
  apply transitivity2 with (B := FnB_nB).
  - is_hypo.
  - is_hypo.
  (* 4 *)
  - set (Fax1 := $~~B -> ~B -> ~~B$).
    apply CutRule with (A := Fax1).
    * apply axiom1.
    (* 5 *)
    * apply transitivity1 with (B := $~B -> ~~B$).
      unfold elem, extend. auto.
      is_hypo.
Qed.

This is like adding the formulas into the proof one by one. But then I thought: is it possible to move backwards applying the operations and filling the holes. Then the proof should look like this:
Theorem neg_neg_pos Γ B : Γ |- $~~ B -> B$.
Proof.
    apply transitivity1 with (A := $~~B$) (B := $~B -> ~~B$) (C := B).
  - (* ~~B -> (~B -> ~~B) *)
    exact (axiom1 $~~B$ $~B$).
  - (* (~B -> ~~B) -> B *)
    apply transitivity2 with (A := $~B -> ~~B$) (B := $~B -> ~B$) (C := B).
    * (* Γ |- (~B -> ~~B) -> (~B -> ~B) -> B *)
      exact (axiom3 B $~B$).
    * (* Γ |- ~B -> ~B) *)
      exact (imply_self $~B$).
Qed.

But it doesn't work because transitivity theorems use statements like $A -> B$ ∈ Γ as hypotheses. And I can't prove that an arbitrary formula belongs to a set.

Can you prove the converse of hypo?  BTW, nice code, I am noting down few things...

@JulioDiEgidio "Can you prove the converse of hypo?" - no, it's impossible. Every hypothesis can be added to the proof. But not everything added to the proof is a hypothesis.

If you prove more flexible versions of transitivity1 and transitivity2 then you can use them more easily.
Theorem transitivity1' {Γ} {A} B {C} :
  Γ |- $A -> B$ ->
  Γ |- $B -> C$ ->
  Γ |- $A -> C$.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply (mp $A -> B$).
  - assumption.
  - apply (mp $A -> B -> C$).
    + now apply drop_antecedent.
    + apply axiom2.
Qed.

Lemma impl_intro {Γ A B} :
  Γ |- $A -> B$ -> extend Γ A |- B.
Proof.
  intro.
  apply (mp A).
  - hypo.
  - apply (weaken Γ).
    + intros. now left.
    + assumption.
Qed.

Theorem transitivity2' {Γ A} B {C} :
  Γ |- $A -> B -> C$ ->
  Γ |- B ->
  Γ |- $A -> C$.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply deduction.
  apply (mp B).
  - apply (weaken Γ).
    + intros. now left.
    + assumption.
  - now apply impl_intro.
Qed.

Theorem neg_neg_pos Γ B : Γ |- $~~ B -> B$.
Proof.
  apply (transitivity1' $~B -> ~~B$).
  - apply axiom1.
  - apply (transitivity2' $~B -> ~B$).
    + apply axiom3.
    + apply imply_self.
Qed.


Are you sure that the theorem Γ |- B -> Γ |- $A -> B$ standard name "drop_antecedent"? I understand why you called it with this name: because we can apply it and prove only the consequent to prove the implication thus dropping the antecedent. But it is exactly axiom1 from Mendelson system: A -> B -> A. In Markin Bocharov it is called "закон утверждения консеквента". The closest translation into English I could make is "the law of consequent affirmation".

Probably, the better name for transitivity2 is flip as it exactly corresponds to Haskell flip function.

I wasn't paying too much attention to theorem names. I have been known to name them cow and rabbit, so this time I think I did pretty well.
